# Compare current date with a date string

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, nsdateformatter

I have a string date in the database which I want to compare with the current date. For example `6/13/2013 11:15:00 PM` is the date in the database, now I want to compare it with today's date. How can I achieve this?

Thanks..

Comment: could you be a little more specific?

Comment: Use `NSDateFormatter` to create a `NSDate` object from the `NSString` and compare it with `[NSDate date]` i.e current date, as per device locale.

Comment: Hi gkovacs90, I store the date as string in the database and I want to compare with today date. For example in database,6/14/2013 11:15:00 PM. I want to compare string date in the database with today date only no time. It will display all the result.

Comment: @user2444511 with comparison of date what do you want to do further???

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *dbDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"your_date_string_from_db"];
if ([dbDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSComparisonResult_value)
{
    //Do what you want accordingly
}
```

NSComparisonResult_value being one of these

```
enum {
   NSOrderedAscending = -1,
   NSOrderedSame,
   NSOrderedDescending
};
```

Comment: Hi Adithya, I getting NSNull when converting from string to date and my date format is 6/13/2013 11:15:00 PM. Do you know why ?

Comment: @Adithya you need to change the dateFormat to `@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one

```
 NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSDate *dt1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDate *dt2 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dt1 = [df dateFromString:yourDatabaseDate];
    dt2 = [df dateFromString:[NSDate date]];
    NSComparisonResult result = [dt1 compare:dt2];
    switch (result)
    {
        case NSOrderedAscending: 
             NSLog(@"%@ is greater than %@", dt2, dt1); 
              break;
        case NSOrderedDescending:  
             NSLog(@"%@ is less %@", dt2, dt1);
             break;
        case NSOrderedSame:
             NSLog(@"%@ is equal to %@", dt2, dt1);
             break;
        default:
             NSLog(@"erorr dates %@, %@", dt2, dt1);
             break;
    }
```